# log4net: Shutdown called on Hierarchy [MyRepository]

Tags: c#, .net, iis, log4net

I have a .net dll configured as a webservice and hosted under IIS. I am handling a scenario where the app pool is abruptly restarted. I enabled "[Process Orphaning](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/asiatech/2014/01/08/how-to-generate-a-dump-file-by-using-process-orphaning-on-iis-67-x/)" which let my executing process live longer and be able to finish its task.

The issue i am facing is with log4net, which i am using for logging, wont log any more after the app pool is recycled. It is working fine until then. So to debug further i enabled the log4net diagnostics using the below

```
  <trace autoflush="true">
    <listeners>
      <add
        name="textWriterTraceListener"
        type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener"
        initializeData="E:\MyPath\Logs\log4net.txt" />
    </listeners>
  </trace>
```

I see the below line repeated multiple times

```
log4net: Shutdown called on Hierarchy [MyRepository]
```

and finally i see this

```
log4net: No appenders could be found for logger [MyName.Space] repository [MyRepository]
log4net: Please initialize the log4net system properly.
```

I did the initialisation correctly because i was getting the log until the app pool recycle correctly and towards the beginning of the log i could see this

```
log4net: Creating repository [MyRepository] using type [log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.Hierarchy]
log4net: configuring repository [MyRepository] using file [E:\MyPath\bin\log4net.config] watching for file updates
log4net: Opening file for writing [...]
log4net: Created Appender [file]
```

What could be preventing log4net to continue to write the log files after the app pool is restarted? In process explorer i can see the w3wp process is still running (Though it is orphaned now and a new process is spawned for subsequent requests).

I used the below section to create an instance of logger.

```
private static readonly log4net.ILog logger = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
```

Log4Net config below

```
<log4net>
  <root>
    <level value="ALL" />
    <appender-ref ref="console" />
    <appender-ref ref="file" />
  </root>
  <appender name="console" type="log4net.Appender.ConsoleAppender">
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%date %level %logger - %message%newline" />
    </layout>
  </appender>
  <appender name="file" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
    <file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="E:\MyPath\myApp_%processid.log" />
    <appendToFile value="true" />
    <rollingStyle value="Size" />
    <maxSizeRollBackups value="1" />
    <maximumFileSize value="10MB" />
    <staticLogFileName value="false" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %level %logger - %message%newline" />
    </layout>
  </appender>
</log4net>
```

Comment: could you share your log config file and which kind of application you are using? also, check the event log for the application pool recycling log.

Comment: event log does show the recycling event. Is there something i should lookout for there like an error or something?

Comment: which kind of application you are using?

Comment: I have updated the web.config. By kind you mean is it a web application?

Comment: yes, web form MVC or something else?

Comment: It is a c# .net web service hosted in IIS (which uses the System.ServiceModel namespace)